# Only xamrin live player

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a problem with Xamarin, i would like to run my program on the simulator like that:
[image_from_turorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0uA1.jpg)
to test my program on computer, without android device

but i only see:
[onli_live_player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdZro.jpg)

When i create project i choose this:
[cross_platform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Olhy1.jpg)

I do not want to use Xamarin live player, someone know what i should do to see such simulation? :
[that_i_want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nr1Nt.jpg)

Comment: Hi, have you solved your problem?

Comment: Thanks for help, but today i can not check this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tools->Android->Android Device Manager->New
[image]

Choose the `Base Device`,`Processor`,`OS` based upon your Android SDK Manager.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install visual studio Android emulator if not already installed and get emulator devices with it